# CSS multiple classes under div

Tags: html, css

```
.TopClass input[type=text]
{
     //Styling 
}
.TopClass textarea
{
     //Same Styling as Above
}
```

So, essentially I am trying to do "Select Text inputs AND textarea inputs under TopClass".

What is the best way to condense this?

Comment: In my answer I assumed that you meant `textarea` rather than `input[type=textarea]`.

Comment: There's no such thing as an `<input type="textarea">`

Comment: Yes, sorry, was in a hurry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need the input for textarea as it is not an input it is its own input element

```
 <textarea type="text"></textarea>
```

and an input

```
 <input type="text"/>
```

but the CSS

```
 .TopClass textarea, .TopClass input[type=text]
 {
 //Same Styling as Above
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use the comma separator:

```
.TopClass input[type=text], .TopClass textarea {
  // Styling
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you need `textarea` instead of `text = textarea`. Try like this:

```
<textarea type="text"></textarea>
```

and input

```
.TopClass textarea, .TopClass textarea {
  // Styling
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.TopClass input[type=text],
.TopClass input[type=textarea]
{
     //Styling 
}
```

And check http://lesscss.org , probably you will like what you find there.

Answer (score 2):

Optimal would be to simplify it this way as both selectors will have same styling applied:

```
 .TopClass input[type=text], .TopClass textarea{

    // styling here

    }
```

Comment: input type=textarea isnt valid